# Another Inclined plane question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

[image: my poor attempt @ FBD...][image]

I did the FBD, and I found too many variables which are not eliminating...Moreover, I believe this question is based on kinetic and static friction. But, $\mu$ here is ambiguously defined...How Do I get the integral value?

Comment: What is $N$? At first, normal force came to mind. But if N is the normal force, and $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction and thus dimension-less, how can $N=10\mu$?

Comment: It is written If WE Define, so maybe, N is just a variable...but my guess is as good as urs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pushing it up, we have to overcome friction(act downwards) as well as the $mg\sin\theta$. So, $$3N=f+mg\sin\theta$$

Now the block is just slipping , so friction is acting upwards, and so does the force applied externally.So,
$$N+f=mg\sin\theta$$

Eliminate $N$ and  use $f=\mu mg\cos\theta$.

Solve for $\mu$ you get your answer.